# Can't return a Text above a GridView inside a Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Good Morning Everybody,

I'm trying to return a Text above a GridView inside a Column. I don't get any error from flutter but when I run it, it only returns the AppBar and nothing else, and in the terminal I get this text:

"Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/39342/Desktop/Development/Sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1927:12"

Here I give you the code I'm using:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('AppBar Text')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            'TEXT EXAMPLE',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 30,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 12.5,
            children: <Widget>[],);
```

Any help or advice will be very much appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: wrap your Gridview inside an Expanded

Answer (score 0):

Listview or GridView when used direct inside column cause this error, This is because of layout [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints). Use SizedBox, Container,Expanded as a parent of `GridView` and it will solve the error.